# React ref syntax and components as pure functions

Tags: reactjs

I have the following TodoApp written in React:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <title>React! React! React!</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="container" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">  </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/babel">
  console.clear();

  const Title = () => {
    return (
      <div>
         <div>
            <h1>to-do</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => {
    // Input Tracker
    let input;
    // Return JSX
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node;
        }} />
        <button onClick={() => {
          addTodo(input.value);
          input.value = '';
        }}>
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const Todo = ({todo, remove}) => {
    // Each Todo
    return (<li onClick={() => {remove(todo.id)}}>{todo.text}</li>);
  }

  const TodoList = ({todos, remove}) => {
    // Map through the todos
    const todoNode = todos.map((todo) => {
      return (<Todo todo={todo} key={todo.id} remove={remove}/>)
    });
    return (<ul>{todoNode}</ul>);
  }

  // Contaner Component
  // Todo Id
  window.id = 0;
  class TodoApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      // Pass props to parent class
      super(props);
      // Set initial state
      this.state = {
        data: []
      }
    }
    // Add todo handler
    addTodo(val){
      // Assemble data
      const todo = {text: val, id: window.id++}
      // Update data
      this.state.data.push(todo);
      // Update state
      this.setState({data: this.state.data});
    }
    // Handle remove
    handleRemove(id){
      // Filter all todos except the one to be removed
      const remainder = this.state.data.filter((todo) => {
        if(todo.id !== id) return todo;
      });
      // Update state with filter
      this.setState({data: remainder});
    }

    render(){
      // Render JSX
      return (
        <div>
          <Title />
          <TodoForm addTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}/>
          <TodoList
            todos={this.state.data}
            remove={this.handleRemove.bind(this)}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.getElementById('container'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Questions:

What is this syntax:

```
const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => {
    // Input Tracker
    let input;
    // Return JSX
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node;
        }} />
```

I think I get what `ref` is but what is that node just inside the curly braces? If it's a function declaration, where are the parenthesis around `node`? What is going on?

Also, at the end, we render the `TodoApp` which renders `TodoForm` like this:

```
<TodoForm addTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}/>
```

Does that just pass addTodo to the functionally declared component, not as `props`, but merely an argument?

`const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => {`

Is this correct? `addTodo` comes in merely as an argument and not as `props`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the following function

```
 const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => {
    // Input Tracker
    let input;
    // Return JSX
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={node => {
          input = node;
        }} />
        <button onClick={() => {
          addTodo(input.value);
          input.value = '';
        }}> 
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

The first line is an example of `destructuring in ES6` What happens is that in `const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => {` props gets passes to the TodoForm Component which is stateless and in the props you have `addTodo` as a prop so out of all the props we are extracting `addTodo`

Also for refs a callback approach is being followed. It is an ES6 style to write a function. Here `node` is an argument and it doesn't contain any parenthesis because it is a single argument and ES6 gives you flexibility to omit the parenthesis. Also inside the `{}` you have the body of the function

In your code node refers to the DOM element and you are assigning its reference to the variable `input` that you have defined. Now you can refer the DOM with `input` rather than assigning ref as `<input ref="myValue"/>` and then refering it as `this.refs.myValue`.

I hope was able to explain it properly.

Read the following **[documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)** on React ref callback approach for a detailed explaination.

Answer (score 0):

let's say we have this one :

```
const TodoForm = (data) => {
  const addTodo = data.addTodo //can be const myFunc = data.addTodo
  // Input Tracker
   ...
```

as an enhancement we can do it like that :

```
const TodoForm = (data) => {
  const {addTodo} = data //can be const {addTodo as myFunc} = data
  // Input Tracker
   ...
```

once more !
as an enhancement we can do it like that :
//notice that we moved the {addTodo} directly to replace data

```
const TodoForm = ({addTodo}) => { 
 //can be ({addTodo: myFunc}) => {
 // Input Tracker
   ...
```